# Как в Windows 10 отправить сообщение в центр уведомлений?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10

Как в Windows 10 отправить сообщение в центр уведомлений?
Не нашел примеры кода на msdn.microsoft.com.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiles_and_toasts/archive/2015/07/08/quickstart-sending-a-local-toast-notification-and-handling-activations-from-it-windows-10.aspx - первая же строчка в Google

Answer (score -1):

Посмотри пример. [ссылка](https://web.archive.org/web/20190204012830/https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/sending-toast-notifications-71e230a2)

Вот тут разьясняют как с ними работать. [ссылка](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tiles_and_toasts/adaptive-and-interactive-toast-notifications-for-windows-10)

Comment: пожалуйста старайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Не используйте только лишь ссылки на сторонние ресурсы в качестве ответа. Ссылки на сторонние ресурсы имеют свойство "умирать" со временем.

Comment: Постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.